# QSslcertificate::verify doesn't check certificate revocation

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

I have a program that verfies a certificate chain. I want to check a certificate revocation by crl.

The program is implemented by Qt. So i used Qt APIs.

I found `QSslcertificate::verify` method. when i read its implementation, I noticed that the method doesn't check the certificate revocation. Is that true that Qt doesn't support a certificate revocation?

If no, what's an alternative way?

**Edit**

If the certificate revocation is supported, should i download the CRL or the method do it automatically?